# How to bind to all elements in a BindingList?

Tags: c#, binding, inotifypropertychanged, bindinglist

I have a `BindingList` consisting of objects of a class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
public MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ...
}

var element1 = new MyClass();
var element2 = new MyClass();
var myBindingList = new BindingList<MyClass> {element1, element2};
```

I'd like to be notified every time one of the elements in my list is changed and run a certain method. How can I bind to all the elements in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this the following way:

```
foreach (MyClass myClass in myBindingList)
{
    myClass.PropertyChanged += MyClassOnPropertyChanged;
}

private void MyClassOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    // ...
}
```